# How to trigger react-router-dom prompt from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

On page change or reload or close, react-router-dom prompt is displaying; however, in my page I am using Material UI tabs and I want the prompt to display on tab change as well.

This is the code for my prompt.

```
    <Prompt
      when={valueChanged}
      message={"Are you sure you want to leave?"}
    />
```

The prompt only displays if I change in the route or close the browser or reload, but how can I make it display without having to change the route (when a change happens on the same page).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using window.confirm instead when wanting to manually displaying the prompt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To see the documentation on how this is used, click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)